# CSS applying rule

Tags: css

I have a CSS rule in a CSS file like this:

```
* { 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
 }
```

What I need to do is not to apply this rule in a given jsp file, how do I do that please?
The rule is applied in all the jsp I imported de CSS file in.

**EDIT:**
Here is mt jsp that I don't want to include that CSS rule in.

```
<body class="avi">
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <jsp:include page="../header/header.jsp"/>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div class="avi_container" style="position:relative;">
            <ul id="avi" data-avi="${avi}" style="display:none;"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--    <div id="footer"> -->
<!--    </div> -->
</div>
<!-- modal content -->
<div id="ibox-modal-content">

    <div id="ibox-modal-title">S&eacute;lectionnez le type d'action :</div>
    <div class="close"><a href="#" class="simplemodal-close"><i class="icon-cancel" style="color: white;"></i></a></div>

    <div id="nodes-nav">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="title field">S&eacute;lectionnez le type d'action</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div id="ibox-modal-data" class="shaded popup">
            <ul class="menulist node-list">
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn active">
                        <a href="message" class="selected node-link" data-action="Prompt" data-display="Message audio">Message Audio</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn">
                        <a href="mevo" class="node-link" data-action="Mevo" data-display="Messsagerie">Messagerie Vocale</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn">
                        <a href="calendar" class="node-link" data-action="Calendar" data-display="Calendrier">Calendrier</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn">
                        <a href="fork" class="node-link" data-action="Fork" data-display="Menu">Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn">
                        <a href="routing/simple" class="node-link" data-action="Routing" data-type="0" data-display="Transfert sur num&eacute;ro">Transfert sur un Numéro</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn">
                        <a href="routing/agent" class="node-link" data-action="Routing" data-type="2" data-display="Transfert sur dispo">Transfert sur Disponibilité</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn">
                        <a href="routing/skill" class="node-link" data-action="Routing" data-type="1" data-display="Transfert sur comp&eacute;tence">Transfert sur Compétence</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="node-item">
                    <div class="medium metro rounded btn">
                        <a href="routing/simple" class="node-link" data-action="Callback" data-display="Call Back">Call Back</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <a href="routing/simple" data-action="Callback" data-display="Call Back">Call Back</a> -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="modal-content" class="row">
            <div id="contentaction">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please give uw more code so we can help u better

Answer (score 2):

In that file, you could override the rule and set the property back to its default value which is `content-box`. Something like this:

```
* { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box; 
     box-sizing: content-box; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That CSS style applies to ALL elements it's a *, change it to something else for example a class for it not to apply.

For example:

```
body.mainpages { 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
 }
```

Then in your HTML when you want it to apply

```
<body class="mainpages"></body>
```